# Ошибка в программе на JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Она принимает через три `JTextField` три числа и определяет по нажатию на кнопку(`JButton`) максимальное из них, записывая ее в четвертую `JTextField`.
Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();


    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    final JTextField firstField  = new JTextField("    ");
    final JTextField secondField  = new JTextField("    ");
    final JTextField thirdField  = new JTextField("    ");
    final JButton button = new  JButton("Выполнить");
    final JTextField resultField = new JTextField("    ");

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            float x = Float.parseFloat(firstField.getText());
            float y = Float.parseFloat(secondField.getText());
            float z = Float.parseFloat(thirdField.getText());

            resultField.setText(Math.max(Math.max(x,y),z));


        }

    });

    frame.add(firstField);
    frame.add(secondField);
    frame.add(thirdField);
    frame.add(button);
    frame.add(resultField);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 100);
    frame.setLocation(500, 500);
    frame.setTitle("Задание 2");
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

Comment: какова рода ошибка возникает?

Comment: Ругается на setText
The method setText(String) in the type JTextComponent is not applicable for the arguments (float)

Comment: @Мария оберните в String.valueof

Comment: ты пытаешся передать float в метод который принимает String. конвертируй float в String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете метод класса `JTextField` со следующей сигнатурой:

```
void setText(float f);
```

Метода с такой сигнатурой в классе `JTextField` не существует. Существует же метод с этой сигнатурой:

```
void setText(String s);
```

Для того, чтобы все заработало, вам нужно добавить перевод из `float` в `String`:

```
resultField.setText(Float.toString(Math.max(Math.max(x,y),z)));
```